# finding which class has triggered blur

Tags: javascript, jquery

I perform validation using the following function:

```
//Validation
$('.sValidate').bind('blur', function() {
    if (!$(this).val()) {
        $(this).removeClass('short_input');
        $(this).addClass('short_input_negative');
        return false;
    }
});
```

Most of my input classes are `short_input`. But some of them are also named `long_input`.
How may I know what class the `input` has that triggered the `blur`, remove it and add `long_input_negative` instead?

```
<input type="text" id="loginname" name="loginname" class="short_input sValidate" value="JDoe">
```

Comment: a class cannot trigger an event

Comment: @Alp It's possible to bind to any element returned by the jQuery selector. More info: http://api.jquery.com/bind/

Answer (score 6):

You can use **[`.hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass)** method for class detection:

```
$('.sValidate').bind('blur',function(){
    if (!$(this).val()){
        if( $(this).hasClass('long_input') ) {
            $(this)
                  .removeClass('short_input');
                  .addClass('short_input_negative');
        }

        if( $(this).hasClass('short_input') ) {
            $(this)
                 .removeClass('long_input');
                 .addClass('long_input_negative');
        }
    }
});
```

From jQuery doc about **`.hasClass()`**

> Determine whether any of the matched elements are assigned the given
>   class.

Another way is using **[`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is)**

```
$('.sValidate').bind('blur',function(){
    if (!$(this).val()){
        if( $(this).is('.long_input') ) {
            // do something of long_input
        }

        if( $(this).is('.short_input') ) {
           // do something of short_input
        }
    }
});
```

From jQuery doc about **`.is()`**

> Check the current matched set of elements against a selector, element,
>   or jQuery object and return true if at least one of these elements
>   matches the given arguments.

Answer (score 0):

While @thecodeparadox has answered your original question, I'd like to point out that »you're doing it wrong«™ - without knowing what your classes actually do. I'm guessing the `foo_negative` class is supposed to switch the color to red or something similarly mundane.

```
.short_input {
  width: 50px;
}

.long_input {
  width: 100px;
}

.negative {
  color: red;
}
```

now that allows you to keep the `short_input` and `long_input` classes and simply add/remove the `negative` class to alter your styling. If you didn't know this, have a look at [MDN CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/).

Answer (score 0):

Here this line `!$(this).val()` returns `false`, if there is some value. So condition never executes.

Do this way:-

```
$('.sValidate').bind('blur',function(){
    if ($(this).val().length > 0){
        if ($(this).hasClass('short_input')) {
            $(this).removeClass('short_input');
            $(this).addClass('short_input_negative');
        }
        if ($(this).hasClass('long_input')) {
            $(this).removeClass('long_input');
            $(this).addClass('long_input_negative');
        }
    }
});​
```

Refer to **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/2dxyW/)**